# Bash command - directory deletion

Tags: svn, jenkins, directory, hudson

I have a very strange problem. On one of my boxes with Hudson deployment, the working copy folder (which is basically an SVN checkout) continually gets deleted every night. Not a huge issue; mostly strange and annoying. Because of this, every morning, I have to perform a full checkout instead of update/switch. It's not a configuration issue in Hudson as far as I know, and I've checked every crontab file to verify that it's not that.

In Linux, is there a bash script or some command line magic to watch a folder, save history about when it is deleted, and who deletes it? This way, I can narrow down what is performing the actual deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be running into [JENKINS-8880](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8880) in which custom workspaces in the node's **workspace/** directory are deleted nightly. The fix is to upgrade to 1.427 (or later), or put custom workspaces outside the **workspace/** directory.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across something similar -- what I did was two-fold.  First, I turned on full system accounting -- this logs what processes get executed and when.  You can narrow down the "when" by looking at the last mod time of the parent directory.

But I don't think the accounting logs show enough detail (process arguments, parent process, etc -- this was on Solaris, you might get more logging options on Linux).  So what I ended up doing is renaming "rm", and writing a shell script called "rm" that called the real one, after logging the input parameters, which process called it, and who owned the calling process.

If a process is calling the unlink system call instead of rm, then you may have to resort to grabbing the source for your C library and adding similar logging functionality to the unlink call.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this question should be tagged "bash".  Many things could be deleting this folder, and bash doesn't include any of its own code to actually delete things.

One option to track down what's happening would be to make it impossible to delete the directory, then see if something in Hudson (or elsewhere) complains of an error.  You can set an "immutable" flag on the parent folder, or on any file in it, and a delete will fail.

In BSD (FreeBSD/NetBSD/etc), use:

```
sudo chflags schg /path/to/directory_or_file
```

In Linux, use:

```
sudo chattr +i /path/to/directory_or_file
```

Now, make sure you're actually *getting* (rather than filtering or null-delivering) all your root and cron messages, turn up the debug level in Hudson (if it has one, I have no idea), then watch and see what happens.

Note that if you add the immutable flag (or schg) to a folder, that does NOT protect the content of subfolders.  It only makes it impossible to delete the directory, or add to or remove files from it.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ mkdir zzz zzz/foo
[ghoti@pc ~]$ touch zzz/bar
[ghoti@pc ~]$ sudo chflags schg zzz
[ghoti@pc ~]$ touch zzz/baz
touch: zzz/baz: Operation not permitted
[ghoti@pc ~]$ touch zzz/foo/baz
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```